# Editable hierarchical grid in Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, grid, hierarchy

I wish to create a grid that each row has grid inside it.

Both grids need to be editable and I managed to do so. However, when I try to add a new row to the outer grid, all the data inside it gone.

You can find the demo here: http://dojo.telerik.com/UqURE

Can you please help with this issue?

Thanks!

```
var outerDataSource= new kendo.data.DataSource({
        schema: {
            model: {
                field1: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } },
                field2: { type: "boolean", validation: { required: true } },
                field3: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } }
            }
        }
    });

$("#outerGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: outerDataSource,
    detailInit: onExpansion,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns: [
        { field: "field1", title: "field1" },
        { field: "field2", title: "field2" },
        { field: "field3", title: "field3" },
        { command: ["destroy"], title: " " }],
    editable: true
});
function onExpansion(e) {
    var insideDataSource= new kendo.data.DataSource({
        schema: {
            model: {
                in1: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } },
                in2: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } }
            }
        },
        data: [{
            in1: "Click to edit",
            in2: "Click to edit"
        }]
    });

    var headers = $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
        dataSource: insideDataSource,
        width: 90,
        toolbar: ["create"],
        editable: true,
        columns: [
          { field: "in1" },
          { field: "in2" },
          { command: ["destroy"], title: "&nbsp;" }]
    });
};
```

Comment: Does `onExpansion` gets called when you click the create button, and if so, does `e.detailCell` point to an existing dom element?

Comment: onExpansion is called at the first time we expand a row. e.detailCell is the expanded row.

Comment: how are you adding new row?

Comment: with "toolbar: ["create"] ". This is a Kendo's feature. You can see the button "Add a new record" on the top of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Telerik:

> Please note that operations like paging, sorting, filtering and
>   editing cause the Grid to rebind and reevaluate all templates inside
>   it (including the details). That why in order to preserve the child
>   Grid data between rebinds you should either save it to remove service
>   (link to documentation here) or add it as navigation property
>   collection to the parent Grid model (demo is available here).

http://www.telerik.com/forums/hirarchialy-editable-grids